# Best PEP8 compliant way to format a long list of lengthy terms in Python

Tags: python, emacs, formatting, pep8

I have a long list of Python terms that looks something like the following:

```
wwwwwwww_wwwww = [
    'wwwwwwww wwwwwww', 'w ww w', 'wwww ww wwwwwww',
    'wwww ww wwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww', 'wwww ww wwwwwww wwwwwww wwwww',
    'wwww ww wwwwwww wwwwwww wwww ww wwwwwww', 'wwww ww wwwwwwww wwww',
    'wwww ww wwwwwwww', 'wwww ww www wwww', 'www wwww',
    'wwww ww wwwwwwww wwwwwww', 'www ww', 'www wwwwwww wwwwwww', 'www www',
    'www wwwwww wwwww wwwwwwwwww', 'www wwwwww wwww wwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww',
    'www wwww wwwwwwwww wwwwwww', 'www wwww wwwwwwwww wwwwwww', 'wwwww',
    'www wwwwwwwww wwww', 'www wwwwww', 'wwww wwwwwwwwww', 'wwww wwwwwwwwwwww',
    'wwwwwwww wwww', 'ww wwwww', 'wwwwww wwwww', 'www wwwww wwwwwwwwww',
    'wwwwww wwww', 'wwwwww wwwwwww wwwwwwww', 'ww wwwwww', 'w w wwwwww',
    'wwww wwwwww', 'www wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwww', 'wwwwww wwwww', 'wwwwwww wwww',
    'wwwwwww wwwww', 'wwwwwww wwwww wwwwww wwwwwwwwww',
    'wwwwwww wwwwww wwwwww wwwwww w wwwww', 'wwwwwww wwwww', 'wwwwww wwwwwwwww',
    'wwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww', 'wwwwww wwwwww wwwwww wwwwwwww',
    'wwwwww wwwwwww wwwwwwww', 'wwww wwwww', 'ww wwwww', 'wwwww wwwww'
]
```

(Note: the top term is not indented at all.)

I believe the above is PEP8 compliant. Each line is under 80 characters horizontally. But it looks a bit ugly due to the jaggedness. Is there a more aesthetic way to format this?

And are there any tools available in Emacs for automatically reformatting it?

Comment: you're probably aware, but the py-autopep8.el library interfaces with autopep8. There are plenty of non-python related alternatives, eg. `fill-paragraph`, which will follow the same max-column (the value of `fill-column`) constrains

Comment: What's wrong with one element per line?

Comment: @chepner that would explode the line count, I'd prefer something more terse.

Comment: What's wrong with exploding the line count? (Arguably, if the list is *that* big, reading it from a configuration file at runtime, or importing it from a separate module, is probably preferable.)

Comment: @chepner honestly that might be the best approach, especially if you need to add, delete, or edit terms. Other things being equal I have a bias towards minimizing line count as it makes the file easier to scan through at a glance.

Comment: I tend to agree, although you can always use code-folding.  It's also nice to have a function that converts between long (exploded lines) and short form (justified list)

Comment: @picklerick do you have any recommendations on enabling code-folding and exploding/compressing lists in Emacs?

Comment: yea, but with the question closed, I can't really answer.  I use modified versions of `fill-region`, `fill-paragraph` (python.el defined `python-fill-paragraph` although I don't think it works well in this case), and a custom fill/unfill list function -- although none of these currently work very well with lists of strings (something I've been meaning to hack).  For code-folding I use built-in hideshow.el mostly